# Javascript: add a character to a string containing a specific word

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have the following string: `table.row.columns.values.many`. I am looking to add character `*` after `values`.
So expected output would be: `table.row.columns.values*.many` .
If there is no `"values"` in string then string should stay the same.

Comment: So, what have you tried to achieve this ? Can you show us ?

Comment: Use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)? It’s unclear what the specific issue is since this should be easy to search for.

Comment: Yeah I can test for "values" and replace it with "values*" but idk if that is right

Comment: @GurbazPooran It’s right if it works. This is easy to test in a console or NodeJS REPL (console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code.

```js
let str = "table.row.columns.values.many"
str = str.replace("values", "values*");
console.log(str);
```

You can use also "replaceAll" if you want to replace all "values".

Answer (score 0):

I think this works nice for you, really simple, and easy way

```
var str = "table.row.columns.values.many";
str = str.replace("values", "values*")

console.log(str)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. `replace` returns another string. If you want to change the original string you need to assign the 'replace' string to the initial string. str = str.replace(....)

Comment: Yeah, now i've did some changes on the code, but nevermind, the right answer is on the top...